# css styling scrollbar button

Tags: css

is there a way to style the scrollbar button arrow color. Each time I use scrollbar-arrow-color: red;the browser overrides it and crosses it out so I'm unable to style it. Is there a work around for this - can you even do it, and if so could someone make jsFiddle for me please. I'm using chrome to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you can do is add a background image to it, something like this

```
.mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
    background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/07/10/55/arrow-975992_960_720.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/hLk2zbfp/)

And [some source material](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) with extensive research